# Why maybe url.length != 0 cause problem if no match is found in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click *"Open Windows"* button in Code A, the two links can be opened in two tabs at one time in Chrome as I expected.

I append a blank line in *textarea* control in Code B, I find only a link http://www.google.com/  can be opened, why?

It seems that *if (url.length != 0) {...}* maybe cause problem, I'm not sure.

**Code A**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="Js/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function open_win() {
            let links = $('#textID').val();
          
            if (links) {
                let row = links.split('\n');
                row.forEach((original_url) => {                    
                    var url = original_url.match(/\b(http|https)?:\/\/\S+/gi)[0];
                    if (url.length != 0) {
                        window.open(url);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <textarea id="textID" name="message" rows="10" cols="80">
     AAA   http://www.google.com/          
     http://www.msn.com/  BBB
    </textarea>

    <br />
    <input type=button value="Open Windows" onclick="open_win()">

</body>

</html>
```

**Code B**

```
//Same
<textarea id="textID" name="message" rows="10" cols="80">
     AAA   http://www.google.com/          

     http://www.msn.com/  BBB
    </textarea>
//Same
```

Comment: When the regexp doesn't match, `.match()` returns `null`, not an array, and you can't use `.length`.

Comment: Change `if (url.length != 0)` to `if (url)`

Comment: Thanks! but `if (url)` doesn't work too.

Comment: And `if (url!= null) {...}` doesn't work too

Comment: You have to check the match before you use `[0]`. I didn't see that at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there's no match `.match()` returns `null`, so you can't access the first element with `[0]`. You have to check for this.

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to avoid lots of extra coding.

```
        if (links) {
            let row = links.split('\n');
            row.forEach((original_url) => {                    
                var url = original_url.match(/\b(http|https)?:\/\/\S+/gi)?.[0];
                if (url) {
                    window.open(url);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm a beginner of javascritp,  what does  `if (url)` mean? does it mean `url` is true?

Comment: Yes. All objects and arrays are truthy, while `null` is falsey. So in this case it's short for `if (url != null)`